# Injective Resolution in Abelian Categories

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an Abelian category. There is a fact that if $\mathcal{C}$ has enough injective objects, then any object in $\mathcal{C}$ has an injective resolution.

By the definition of "*$\mathcal{C}$ has enough injective objects*", $\forall A\in\mathcal{C} $ , there exists a monomorphism from $A$ to an injective object in $\mathcal{C}$, i.e., the sequence
$$
0\longrightarrow A \longrightarrow I^0
$$
is exact. The coker$(A \longrightarrow I^0 )$ is an object in $\mathcal{C}$. Again, because of the definition of "*$\mathcal{C}$ has enough injective objects*", we can choose a monomorphism 
$$
coker(A \longrightarrow I^0 ) \longrightarrow I^1 
$$
s.t. $I^1$ is an injective object. Then we have an exact sequence
$$
0\longrightarrow A \longrightarrow I^0 \longrightarrow I^1.
$$
Repeating the above process, we get an injective resolution.

My question is how to use the monomorphism $coker(A \longrightarrow I^0 ) \longrightarrow I^1$ to prove the sequence $0\longrightarrow A \longrightarrow I^0 \longrightarrow I^1$ is exact at $I^0$. I need more details about it.

Thanks. Any commentary is welcome.

Comment: Can you do it when $\mathcal{C}$ is (e.g.) the category of abelian groups?

Answer (score 0):

You have the composition $A \overset{\varphi}{\to} I^0 \overset{\mathrm{coker} \varphi}{\to} \mathrm{coker}(A \to I^0) \to I^1$, but $\mathrm{coker}(A \to I^0) \to I^1$ is a monomorphism, so $\ker(I^0 \to I^1) = \ker(\mathrm{coker}(\varphi)) = \mathrm{im}(\varphi)$. So essentially it follows because we defined the image as the kernel of the cokernel.

Hope that helps,